# Cors Issue with Hyper Ledger Private Block chain network on Aws

Tags: aws, besu, cors

I am new to hyper ledger and trying to set up a private block chain network with clique as consensus protocol. I am deploying it on a AWS Ec2 Instance.

Followed these steps and initiated a boot node and another node

https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/1.3.6/Tutorials/Private-Network/Create-Private-Clique-Network/

***boot node***

/home/ubuntu/hyperledger/besu-21.10.8/bin/besu --data-path=data --genesis-file=/home/ubuntu/nodeInfo/conf/cliqueGenesis.json --network-id 123 --rpc-http-enabled --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,CLIQUE --host-allowlist="*" --rpc-http-cors-origins="all" --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --p2p-host=18.206.81.119

***another node***

/home/ubuntu/hyperledger/besu-21.10.8/bin/besu --data-path=data --genesis-file=/home/ubuntu/nodeInfo/conf/cliqueGenesis.json --bootnodes=enode://d0ec80fc5af05fd7700c5c7b2fa9e268d93c3bc641efe917791b8da3baede296c16a313f6b6b27d4ccc3c267f507ca4acb17271ebace64633635e755edec882c@18.206.81.119:30303 --network-id 123 --p2p-port=30305 --rpc-http-enabled --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,CLIQUE --host-whitelist="*" --rpc-http-cors-origins="all" --rpc-http-port=8547

when we tried to add this network to metamask ,we got the CORS Exception

Rpc Url: http://NodepublicIp:8545 , http://NodepublicIp:8546 and http://NodepublicIp:8547

I have opened relevant ports 8545 to 8547 for communication on Ec2.

Provide us some pointers to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You say you have opened ports 8545 to 8547 but have you done the same for ports 30303 to 30305? I'm not sure if this matters when using a single EC2 instance though.

https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/HowTo/Find-and-Connect/Configuring-Ports/